# Front facing Camera : setparameters failed Exception On Sony xperia device

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm building camera application with front and rear camera support. I've **issue on sony xperia device** for **front camera**. I'm using this code..

```
try {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setRotation(90);
        if (shouldShowFlashlight) {
            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "####### setting FLASH_MODE_TORCH");
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        } else {
            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "####### NOT setting FLASH_MODE_TORCH");
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

My issue is that this code works on all other devices for front & rear camera's. Even on sony experia, code works fine for rear camera. But, **for front camera, it is failing to setparameters** for mPreviewSize.width & mPreviewSize.height... which is unfortunately results into an

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

I need help to fix this issue.

Comment: Please don't add "*Help me ASAP!*" and Thank Yous to your questions. First, people are not going to help you any faster because you think that your question is more important and urgent than other people's questions. Second, they both add nothing of value to solving the problem posed in your question, and are just *really* distracting noise, which is not something that helps you.

Comment: Which specific preview size fails? Did you reset `mSupportedPreviewSizes` after switching to front camera?

Comment: @ Cupcake I understand you.... But, for me it is too much important to get that resolved....

Comment: @Alex Cohn Yes, I'm reseting mSupportedPreviewSizes after switching to front camera..

Comment: ... and the resolution you choose is?